# How can I view which Pokémon I've buddied over time?

Tags: pokemon-go

Ever since the Buddy feature was released in the version [0.37.0 Android/1.7.0 iOS](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-091016/), I have buddied a variety of Pokémon. After buddying so many, I would like to see which Pokémon I have buddied in the past and how many kilometers they received from them.

How can I view which Pokémon I've buddied?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version [0.49.1 Andorid/1.19.1 iOS](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-120616/) released a feature which allows you to view each Pokémon you have buddied and how many kilometers you have accumulated with that Pokémon.

> The total kilometers a buddy has walked has been added to the information screen of each Pokémon that has ever been your buddy.